# Querying against multiple columns in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to execute a query against multiple columns in EF 6 (using C# WPF on VS 2013), I need to select all fields of some columns. I really don't know much but I already tried to do it with Linq and it doesn't seem to have that functionality, so I went with `<context>.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query)`, but it's unclear to me how should I handle what it returns. The query is something simple like `"SELECT column1,column2 FROM table"`.

Is it possible to do it with `Linq`? How? And for the `SqlQuery()` case, How should I handle it's result, being most of its columns are in string format?

Comment: Yes, it's possible using linq: `context.Table.Select(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 });`.

Comment: Hey! MarcinJuraszek, thanks for the quick answer. How do I handle it? I put ToArray() but I guess it should be an IEnumerable or something, but it says AnonymousType#1

Comment: @MiloGP What you have done so far ?? Can you post some code ??

Comment: I made this, I'm not so sure but something like that worked before for me. string[] lista = (db.tbl_pacientes.Select(x => new { x.pac_pk_id, x.pac_nombre1 })).ToArray();

Comment: @MiloGP Post an answer if you found something that worked for you.

Comment: @Shoe I haven't solved it yet, code I posted was an attempt but didn't work. I will post as soon as I find an answer.

Comment: What didn't work about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@MiloGP yes you can do it with using Lambda Expression with LINQ

Here a example:

I have 5 columns in table employee(emp_id,emp_name,emp_dob,emp_address,emp_reference)

and My DBContext name : EmployeeEntities;

I trying to get emp_name and emp_address

`List<employee> = EmployeeEntities.employees.select( x => new { x.emp_name, x.emp_address }).ToList();`

if you need to get value of someone, As a example emp_id == 13458

`List<employee> = EmployeeEntities.employees.Select( x => new { x.emp_name, x.emp_address }).Where( y => y.emp_id == 13458).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks! That's the way. But what I was actually trying to do was getting all values without the need to specify all the field names, as there's a lot of fields in some of the tables on the project. But I guess that's not possible. Is it?

Comment: No it is possible.. To get all of the fields you have to change the code to following.

List<employee> = EmployeeEntities.employees.ToList();

It will get all the employees. if need to get someone details then use following.

List<employee> = EmployeeEntities.employees.Where(x=>x.emp_id == 13458).ToList();